# updating a MYSQL table value with a circular reference

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, circular-reference

I have two tables:

```
AGENT
--------
agent_id
user_id
...
```

and

```
USER
-----
user_id
agent_id
user_name
...
```

I'm not here to discuss why this was done, but I have question regarding being able to update USER.AGENT_ID to the correct value if I only know the USER.user_name value (always unique).

I've tried:

```
update USER U set U.agent_id = 
  (select A.agent_id from agent A where A.user_id = 
     (select tu.user_id from user tu where tu.user_name = 'myusername')
  )
where U.user_name = 'myusername';
```

However, this doesn't work and gives me errors. How should I be doing this?

Comment: you can't update a table from which you're selecting. See 3rd last paragraph here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html You'll have to run a separate select query, get your id, then run the update

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow `SELECT` from the same table you're updating in an `UPDATE`, but you can do a multi-table update with a JOIN:

```
UPDATE USER u JOIN AGENT A ON A.user_id = u.user_id
SET U.agent_id = A.agent_id
WHERE u.user_name = 'myusername';
```

Also, using the subqueries as you were doing was probably complaining that it couldn't guarantee the subquery would return a single scalar value, because you were selecting based on searching a non-unique column.